# How do I prevent duplicate guesses in number guessing game?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml

I created an array called tries to collect what numbers the user has guessed. When the user finally guesses the correct number, the number of tries and what numbers were guessed told to the user. How would I avoid the user guessing a number that they already guessed? I know I will have to check the array after every guess to see if that number has been guessed already and is in the array. (if guess is in array, show message saying "You guessed that already, try again") Also, should I add that guess to the number of guesses or do no include it since it is a repeat guess?

```
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

console.log(num);

let num_guess = 0
let tries = []

function do_guess() {
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

    let message = document.getElementById("message");

    if (isNaN(guess)) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
    }
    else if (guess > 20) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.';
        num_guess++
        tries.push(guess)
    }
    else if (guess > num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
        num_guess++
        tries.push(guess)
    }
    else if (guess < num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
        num_guess++
        tries.push(guess)
    }
    else if (guess == num) {
        num_guess++
        tries.push(guess)
        message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + num_guess + " tries and your guesses were " + tries + ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: As for whether to include a repeat guess in the number of guesses - that's up to you and how you want your game to work. You've made an out of range value count as a guess, so .....

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `Array.includes`:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(1)
> true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4)
> false
```

On whether you want to include the duplicate guesses: it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an element exists in an array or not.

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain
> value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

You need to add following code before all condition

```
if (tries.includes(guess)) {
        message.innerHTML = "You guessed that already, try again";
    }
```

```js
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

console.log(num);

let num_guess = 0;
let tries = [];
const guessContainer = document.getElementById("guess");
const check = document.getElementById("check");
let message = document.getElementById("message");

guessContainer.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  message.innerHTML = "";
});

function do_guess() {
  let guess = Number(guessContainer.value);
  let isCorrect = false;

  if (tries.includes(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = "You guessed that already, try again";
  } else if (isNaN(guess)) {
    message.innerHTML = "That is not a number!";
  } else if (guess > 20) {
    message.innerHTML = "That number is not in range, try again.";
    num_guess++;
    tries.push(guess);
  } else if (guess > num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    num_guess++;
    tries.push(guess);
  } else if (guess < num) {
    message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    num_guess++;
    tries.push(guess);
  } else if (guess == num) {
    isCorrect = true;
    num_guess++;
    tries.push(guess);
    message.innerHTML =
      "You got it! It took you " +
      num_guess +
      " tries and your guesses were " +
      tries +
      ".";
  }
  if (isCorrect) {
    message.classList.add("right");
    message.classList.remove("wrong");
  } else {
    message.classList.add("wrong");
    message.classList.remove("right");
  }
}

check.addEventListener("click", do_guess);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

button {
  background-color: indianred;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrong {
  color: tomato;
}

.right {
  color: green;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="guess" />
<button id="check">check</button>
<h5 id="message"></h5>
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it is what you're expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

console.log(num);

var num_guess = 0;
var tries = [];
function go_guess() {

  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
  
  let message = document.getElementById("message");
  if(tries.includes(guess)){
    message.innerText = "You guessed that already, try again";
  } else {
    
    if (isNaN(guess)) {
      message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
    }
    else if (guess > 20) {
      message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.';
      num_guess++;
      tries.push(guess);
    }
    else if (guess > num) {
      message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
      num_guess++;
      tries.push(guess);
    }
    else if (guess < num) {
      message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
      num_guess++;
      tries.push(guess);
    }
    else if (guess == num) {
      let _tries = `${tries[0]}`;
      for(let i = 1;i<tries.length;i++){
        _tries += `, ${tries[i]}`;
      }
      num_guess++;
      message.innerText = `You got it! It took you  ${num_guess} tries and your guesses were ${_tries}.`;
    }
  };
});
```